# Analysing the coefficients of a linear regression from multiple data sets

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing

I have a constrained regression equation of the form $Y = a_iX_i$ from 10 data sets, where each $a_i \geq 0$ and each predictor $X_i$.

Focusing on the coefficients of the predictors (5 terms), is it possible to create a test saying that some coefficients are greater than others (in terms of magnitudes)?

For example: I want to say that $a_1 > a_2 > ... $. I want to be able to create this comparison on the predictors.

Comment: When you say magnitude, will you fix this at some amount? eg. $a_1=10a_2=100a_3...$ ? If so, you might be able to set a matrix of contrasts and compare them that way.

Comment: Could you give some context, and explain why you have omitted intercepts? See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7948/when-is-it-ok-to-remove-the-intercept-in-a-linear-regression-model